# How do I get other angles in orthographic view?

Tags: 3d-view

I want to see an angle in between front and side view that's exacly like front and side view - orthographic with the grid. However when I change the angle the grid disappears and it changes to perspective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Numpad keys to freely switch from perspective to orthographic views.

Numpad <kbd>5</kbd> toggles perspective/orthographic view mode without changing your camera angle.

Comment: that's what I'm doing, but it's still not showing the grid in anything but the straight angles

Comment: Oh, so if I understand correctly, you're trying to view the XZ grid for example while you're not axis aligned to it?

Comment: yes so I can align my reference image from different angles

Comment: I don't think that has been implemented into Blender, did a bit of poking around and it seems you can only view/hide the grid while you're in the ortho front, side etc views. :-/

Comment: okay well thanks for looking